# How to prevent false values from being added in meteor-autoform and SimpleSchema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, schema

I have a MongoDB collection with an attached SimpleSchema inside a Meteor application. On the frontend I'm using `quickform` from the `meteor-autoform` package to quickly render a form.  (https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-autoform)

```
export const MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('my-collection');
export const MySchema = new SimpleSchema({

  name: {
    type: String
  },

  isSuperDuper: {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: true
  }

});

MyCollection.attachSchema(MySchema);

const exampleDoc = { name: 'Waka Waka' };
MyCollection.insert(exampleDoc);
```

Frontend form:

```
{{> quickForm collection="MyCollection" doc=myDoc id="updateMyDoc" type="update"}}
```

The `quickform` loads my exampleDoc with the isSuperDuper Boolean having an assigned value of `false`. I'm seeing it on the client in the console with `AutoForm.getFormValues('updateMyDoc')` If I check the mongo shell there is no `isSuperDuper` key, as expected. The second I save the quickForm (without making any changes) the doc is assigned `isSuperDuper: false`.

Is it possible to use `quickform` without it automatically converting empty Booleans from my schema into `false` values?

I have tried messing with the quickform settings `autoConvert=false` and `removeEmptyStrings=false` to no avail.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are other factors at play here. SimpleSchema is going to define your schema and validate it, but not insert other properties. Is there more code around "inserting" that you might want to share?

Comment: Thanks @Chase, you were right. The issue is coming from the autoform quickform being used on the client. I've updated my question.

Comment: Are you using a checkbox in your form? A checkbox would only have two values -- true or false. You would instead need to use a select or radio that allows a third "undefined' state.

Comment: Quickform automatically generates the form based on the schema, I do not manually add any fields. It renders a text field called "Name" with my "Waka Waka" value already populated. Then comes the checkbox called "isSuperDuper" which is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the issue is you are using the default "checkbox" which only has two possible states (checked/unchecked). Unchecked would map to `false`.

See this section of the documentation: https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-autoform#affieldinput

```
If you don't include a type attribute, the following logic is used to automatically select an appropriate type:

...


* Otherwise if the schema type is Boolean, the boolean-checkbox
  type is used. You may want to specify a type of boolean-radios
  or boolean-select instead. If you do so, use the trueLabel,
  falseLabel, and nullLabel attributes to set the labels used 
  in the radio or select control.
```

This sounds like you can specify radio or select options to allow for a null state which may produce better results for an optional boolean (essentially giving it a third state).

Comment: From above: Quickform automatically generates the form based on the schema, I do not manually add any fields. It renders a text field called "Name" with my "Waka Waka" value already populated. Then comes the checkbox called "isSuperDuper" which is unchecked.

Comment: I know, this explains why that is a problem. A unchecked checkbox means `false`.

Comment: Which brings us back to my original question: Is it possible to use quickform without it automatically converting empty Booleans from my schema into false values?

Comment: Yes, exactly as I described. You have not stated a requirement it must be shown in the form as a checkbox. This is why the other two types exist.

Comment: Its form is irrelevant. It must be using quickform though as stated in OP.

Comment: I'm unclear if you've read the answer and the linked documentation. It uses quickform.... If you don't specify anything different it uses the default. You do not like the default, so specify one of the other two.